# Equivalent definitions of module homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, morphism

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1. Let $f:R\times R\to R$ be a map.

The claim: $f$ is an homomorphism of $R$-modules iff $\exists\,\alpha,\beta\in R: f((x,y))=\alpha x+\beta y\,\forall\,x,y\in R$.

I'm working on the if direction.

What I got so far:
One of the things we want to show is $f((a,b)+(c,d))=f(a,b)+f(c,d)$.

We know that $f((a,b)+(c,d))=f((a+c,b+d))$. Then by the assumption, $\exists\,\alpha_{0},\beta_{0}\in R:f((a+c,b+d))=\alpha_{0}(a+c)+\beta_{0}(b+d)=\alpha_{0}a+\alpha_{0}c+\beta_{0}b+\beta_{0}d$.

Then we want this to be equal to $f(a,b)+f(c,d)$. By assumption, $\exists\,\alpha_{1},\beta_{1},\alpha_{2},\beta_{2}\in R:f(a,b)+f(c,d)=\alpha_{1}a+\beta_{1}b+\alpha_{2}c+\beta_{2}d$

If we want $f((a,b)+(c,d))=f(a,b)+f(c,d)$, then we'd need to have $\alpha_{0}=\alpha_{1}=\alpha_{2},\beta_{0}=\beta_{1}=\beta_{2}$, but I don't understand why that would have to be true.

Sorry if this is a dumb question . . . the book I'm reading says this direction is clear, but I don't see it.

Comment: The RHS of the claim should be ($\exists \alpha,\beta\in R)\ (\forall x,y\in R) f(x,y)=\alpha x+\beta y$ (meaning $\alpha,\beta$ should not depend on $x,y$; otherwise $\impliedby$ would not hold indeed).

Comment: Oh . . . I didn't write it down correctly, and I didn't realise they meant $\alpha,\beta$ didn't depend on $x,y$. I thought it meant for any $x,y$ you can find some $\alpha,\beta$. But it was supposed to be that there exist some $\alpha,\beta$ such that for every $x,y$ we have $f((x,y))=\alpha x+\beta y$. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint: If $f$ is a homomorphism, then it is uniquely determined by $\alpha := f(1,0)$ and $\beta := f(0,1)$.